# When I press each of the 27 VM joystick buttons, I observe no confirmation on the Windows Game Controller test screen

Tags: windows-7, usb, joystick

This afternoon:

- I connected the VM desktop Joystick to an USB port on a Windows desktop computer.
- A new hardware detection window appeared in the lower right corner of the screen called USB Input Device.
- I tested the Window's Game Controllers utility.
- I clicked properties to access the Windows Controllers Test Screen.

When I move the joystick and X Rotation dial - I observe confirmation on the Test Screen that they are working okay. But, when I press each of the 27 buttons - there is no confirmation on the Test Screen that they are working properly.

Is there additional software such as device drivers that we need to install? Do we need to configure the joystick buttons?

Alternatively, should we ignore the fact that when I press each of the 27 buttons, I observe no confirmation on the Test Screen that they are working properly because it is responsibility of the HID C library to process joystick button presses?

Yesterday, I visited Winston-Salem's best computer store and brought in my CH Products VM Desktop Joystick and had them test it. The salesman - who is usually reliable - told me:

> There was something wrong with it. Windows 7 or 8 cannot recognize it.

Was he correct in his conclusion?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please tell me the Vendor ID and Product ID for the CH  Products VM Desktop joystick.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the CH Products, Setup Control Manager software. on my Windows 7 desktop. After installation, I still find that when I press each of the 27 VM joystick buttons, I observe no confirmation on the Windows Game Controller test screen .

Comment: What does this question have to do with C++?

Comment: @DavidPostill, The reason I marked this question with C++ is eventually I wish to have a C++ program which uses the Raw Input Human Interface Device(HID) protocol connect with a CH Products VM desktop Joystick. Please let us know if you have any ideas.

Comment: But it's not relevant to **this** question. Tag removed.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer store salespeople were wrong in their conclusion. There is no C++ API for controlling the buttons on as CH Products VM desktop Joystick, The reason I came to this conclusion is that I tried to build  hidapi.dll written by Alan Ott of Signal Technologies. I got this following Visual Studio C++ linker error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall HidP_GetCaps(struct _HIDP_PREPARSED_DATA .... fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals

Comment: I talked with CH Products this morning and they assert that the button events are not captured because of a hardware failure instead of an  Visual Studio C++ linker error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol .named ( HidP_GetButtonCaps(HidP_Input, pButtonCaps, &capsLength, pPreparsedData)